# Cannot use postgres jsonb operator ?| using spring jpa

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to search entities where at least one element from array exists in jsonb array.
For this I can use an sql query:

```
select * from person where roles ?| array['ROLE_1','ROLE_2'];
```

But in case of spring jpa this is not valid:

```
@Query(value = "select * from person where roles ?| array['ROLE_1','ROLE_2']", nativeQuery = true)
```

The error is following:

```
At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
```

I understand that the problem is in special char **?** which spring interpret as a required parameter in repository method (say there is method *findRole1OrRole2()*), but how I can handle that?

Comment: I don't use `Spring JPA`, but this [Named Parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.4.3/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) looks like something worth trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the internal implementation of operation `?|`, under the hood it invokes the procedure `jsonb_exists_any(jsonb , text[])`, so the possible solution is:

```
@Query(value = "select * from person where jsonb_exists_any(roles, array['ROLE_1','ROLE_2'])", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, you should escape the question mark by doubling it: `??|`

Comment: Thanks for comment! It doesn't work, there is the same error msg